# RegisterClass failed: class already exits

Tags: windows, winapi

When I create a child window for the second time,

```
if (!::RegisterClass(&hwClass))
{
    throw std::runtime_error("RegisterClass failed!");
}
```

It throws an exception that the class already exists. but the child window class was deleted when the child window was destroyed at:

```
WM_DESTROY:
{
   delete this;  //destroy child class
}
```

It works if I comment the expection error. does that mean I don't need to register a class again?

Comment: Wrong comment, should be // destroy window object wrapper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [`UnregisterClass` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644899(v=VS.85).aspx), which states:

> Before calling this function, an application must destroy all windows created with the specified class.

Indicates that destroying the windows *doesn't* unregister the class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should not register the class again.

This is from MSDN:

> All window classes that an application
>   registers are unregistered when it
>   terminates.

**Update:**
This makes sense because many windows can be created based on a window class and a window class exist before creating any window.