# Re-registering User-defined Window Class - C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm getting a class already exists error from the call to `RegisterClassEx` in the following code.  This code is in a class constructor:

```
this->m_wcx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);  // size of structure
this->m_wcx.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; // initially minimized
this->m_wcx.lpfnWndProc = &WndProc;       // points to window procedure
this->m_wcx.cbClsExtra = 0;               // no extra class memory
this->m_wcx.cbWndExtra = 0;               // no extra window memory
this->m_wcx.hInstance = m_hInstance;      // handle to instance
this->m_wcx.hIcon = ::LoadIcon( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION ); // default app icon
this->m_wcx.hCursor = ::LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW ); // standard arrow cursor
this->m_wcx.hbrBackground = NULL;         // no background to paint
this->m_wcx.lpszMenuName = NULL;          // no menu resource
this->m_wcx.lpszClassName = s_pwcWindowClass; // name of window class
this->m_wcx.hIconSm = NULL;               // search system resources for sm icon

// Register window class.
if ( (this->m_atom = ::RegisterClassEx( &m_wcx )) == 0 )
{
    dwError = ::GetLastError();
    TRACE(_T("Failed to register window class.\r\n\tError: %d\r\n\tFile: %s\r\n\tLine: %d\r\n"), dwError, _T(__FILE__), __LINE__);
    THROW(dwError);
}
```

This first time this code executes, it works without any problems.  When the class destructor is called it unregisters the class:

```
::UnregisterClass( s_pwcWindowClass, this->m_hInstance );
```

This all works fine the first time through.  Subsequent calls to the constructor result in `RegisterClassEx` failing with `ERROR_CLASS_ALREADY_EXISTS`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the destructor for the first instance is getting called before you create the second instance?

Comment: @unaperson: Yes.  I'm running this from a test application, unless there is a fatal error, which would be logged, the destructor only gets called when I manually instruct it to be called.

Comment: Did you check the return value of `UnregisterClass`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638988/registerclass-failed-class-already-exits

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`UnregisterClass()` will fail (will not delete the class) if there are windows of that class in the system. So you will need to `::DestroyWindow()` for all windows that were created with the class.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't unregister a class when it is needed later on anyway. I'd test for ERROR_CLASS_ALREADY_EXISTS like so:

```
ATOM reg=RegisterClassEx(&m_wcx);
DWORD err=GetLastError();
if(!reg && !(err==ERROR_CLASS_ALREADY_EXISTS)){
    //throw only if not successful and not already registered
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I am sure that I destroy the only window that created using specified class and then call UnregisterClass and it return TRUE(1) but it seems that it doesn't remove the class from the system and I get ERROR_ALREADY_EXIST from next call to RegisterClassEx